# Verificar se a página html existe HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para quando clicar no link automaticamente verifica se a página está online? Sem php.

Comment: Você não especificou se quer verificar uma página do mesmo domínio ou não. Se for de um domínio diferente do da sua aplicação, você não conseguirá fazer essa verificação por conta do *CORS*.

Comment: Acho que duplicada desta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123868/verificar-se-url-existe/123966#123966, ou ao menos relacionada.

Answer (score 9):

Se o site que esta tentando verificar for em um domínio diferente você terá bloqueio provavelmente terá bloqueio com CORS, leia mais em:

> [Controle de Acesso HTTP (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)

Fora que é importante saber que sites off-line podem ser qualquer coisa, pode ser uma página desabilitada que emite um código de status HTTP ou pode realmente estar offline ("desligado") e não vai nem chegar a conectar, então a resposta do @13dev não irá funcionar:

```
200: function () {
    alert('site esta on!');
},
400: function() {
    alert("site off!");
}
```

Pois este script só checa o status HTTP, fora que em jQuery não existe o atributo `method:` o correto é `type:`

O melhor para checar com jQuery seria usar assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://meusite.com",
    type: "HEAD"
}).done(function () {
     alert('Online');
}).fail(function () {
     alert('Provavelmente offline');
});
```

No entanto isto ainda tem o problema do CORs provavelmente.

O código do @Godfrey também talvez não funcione em navegadores modernos (talvez no futuro), isto porque esta em modo síncrono e isto esta em desuso pelos navegadores e logo será removido:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET",uri,false);
xhr.send(null);
if(xhr.status == 200) { // A página está online.
     return xhr.responseText;
}
```

O melhor é usar `onreadystatechange`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var uri = "http://site.com";

xhr.open("GET", uri, true); //Defina TRUE

//Usando callback
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) { // A página está online.
         alert("online");
    } else {
         alert("provalmente offline");
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

### Não tem maneira garantida de checar a conectividade no front-end

Por questões de CORs como já disse não tem como checar se um site esta online de fato, infelizmente **a única solução confiável é usando back-end**, mesmo que não tenha sido o que você solicitou ainda sim recomendo que reveja isto.

Exemplos em PHP:

Checando se um site esta disponível e a porta 80 (que é a porta HTTP esta disponível)

```
if (!fsockopen("www.site-externo.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
    echo "Offline";
} else {
    echo "Online";
}
```

O código anterior só checa se o site esta online, mas não checa se a página que consultou é "valida" (retorna código HTTP entre 200 e "299"), no entanto se quiser checar isto também pode usar `curl`:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.site-externo.com/pagina-especifica';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Não retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
    echo 'Offline, detalhes do erro: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) {
        echo 'Online';
    } else {
        echo 'Offline, resposta HTTP: ' . $httpcode;
    }
}
```

Outra maneira **não tão garantida**, mas ainda sim **mais garantida que com o Ajax** seria usar `document.createElement('script')` com um resource `.js` do site externo.

Comment: Ho Boa idéia, (51) rs, me diga a url entra aonde?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo veja se consegue entender agora os códigos, de qualquer forma a resposta é explicar que estas soluções que o 13dev e o Godfrey postaram não são praticaveis e podem causar mais problemas que resolver algo.

Comment: Eu entendi, só que estava faltando a uri na sua resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Cara... Ele deixou explícito que não deseja fazer a verificação no backend.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing a resposta fala bem mais do que outro dominio, fala: *"se for outro dominio, se não for vai funcionar"*

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Então retire a parte desnecessária à pergunta. Sockets, etc... Corresponde ao backend.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing não tem nada de desnecessário, eu respondo a pergunta dentro do enunciado, expliquei a diferença de resposta HTTP e de um servidor offline de fato e os exemplos em PHP são um adicional que ajudam a entender as diferenças entre socket e resposta HTTP.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing fora que não tem muita lógica verificar se o site que você já esta navegando esta online, então é bem mais provavel que ele esteja realmente querendo verificar se um site externo esta online.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a minha resposta foi virada para a mais simples como citei, mas ja editei tinhas razão, obrigado pela informação + 1!

Comment: @13dev obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

O mais simples de todo seria fazeres uma requisição ajax para verificar se pagina existe:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://meusite.com",
    type: "HEAD"
}).done(function() { 
      alert('Site existe!');
}).fail(function() { 
      alert('Site não existe!');
})
```

**OBS**
Lembrando que isso não irá funcionar se o domínio a ser buscado não é o mesmo da aplicação. 
Por conta do header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Fala mestre acho que tem algo estranho na sua resposta, statusCode 404 Site On ?

Comment: mente confusa ! ja esta correto ahah, obrigado é que nem notei!

Comment: Lembrando que isso não irá funcionar se o domínio a ser buscado não é o mesmo da aplicação. Por conta do header **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**.

Comment: @GodfreytheKing tens toda a razão irei editar!

Answer (score 0):

Você não especificou se quer verificar se a página pertence ao mesmo domínio e se deseja a resposta utilizando jQuery... De qualquer forma:

```
function checkPage() {
    // Colocar aqui a url.
    var url = ''
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",url ,false);
    xhr.send(null);
    if(xhr.status == 200) { // A página está online.
     return xhr.responseText;
    }

    // Está offline.
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo, não consegui entender a sua dúvida. Por exemplo: `var url = "meudominio.com.br"`.

Comment: Yep, problema na digitação ;)

Comment: Blz, foi só pra ficar certinha sua resposta